# How to use ssh without knowing remote user's password?

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, password, terminal, restrictions

I am trying to use ssh and login to a different mac (B) from my mac (A) but do not know B's password. Is there anyway of finding B's password or doing this without access to B?

Comment: If you can place your SSH public key on B, you may be able to connect using your SSH private key without using a password.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do that. Without having access to the other mac you cannot place your key in order to log in.

You would have to have prior knowledge of the password otherwise.

Comment: Is there a way of changing the users password

Comment: This is getting into an area that is frowned upon on this site: http://serverfault.com/tour

Comment: @MaanitMadan do you own that machine, or are you responsible for it?  Go to the machine physically boot it off the installer media.  There is a password reset tool.